# How to generate SDO_GEOMETRY for geolatte Geometry with JPA Buddy

Tags: liquibase, changelog, jpa-buddy

I am using JPA Buddy to generate Liquibase changelog from a JPA-annotated Entity in Kotlin.

My model looks something like this:

```kotlin
@Entity
class MyEntity(
  @Id
  val id: Long,

  val someField: String,

  @Type(JsonBlobType::class)
  val someStruct: SomeClass,

  val geometry: Geometry<*>,
)
```

When I use the `Liquibase init` generation, all fields are generated except the geometry field. I have tried adding a mapping in `jpb-settings.xml`:

```xml
          <mapping-type sql-type-parameter="Nothing">
            <java-class>org.geolatte.geom.Geometry</java-class>
            <sql-type>MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY</sql-type>
          </mapping-type>
```

But this has no effect.

How can I make JPA Buddy generate a Liquibase changelog that includes geometry fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make JPA Buddy pay attention to the type you want is to use the @Column annotation along with the columnDefinition attribute. For example, this column declaration worked for me.

```
import jakarta.persistence.*
import org.geolatte.geom.Geometry
import org.geolatte.geom.Position

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
open class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    open var id: Long? = null

    @Column(name = "geometry", columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
    open var geometry: Geometry<*>? = null
}

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.19.xsd"
        objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ONLY_RESERVED_WORDS">

    <changeSet id="1685444752395-1"
               author="vlasov (generated)">
        <createTable tableName="my_entity">
            <column autoIncrement="true"
                    name="id"
                    type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             primaryKey="true"
                             primaryKeyName="pk_my_entity"/>
            </column>
            <column name="geometry"
                    type="MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the name was sufficient! I wanted to avoid hardcoding the column definition, since I use the same entity for H2 and Oracle. By changing the mapping to:
```
          <mapping-type sql-type-parameter="Nothing">
            <java-class>org.geolatte.geom.Geometry&lt;?&gt;</java-class>
            <sql-type>MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY</sql-type>
          </mapping-type>
```
everything works!